# Create Database login in code

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I have an application that creates and uses its own SQL Server Express database. It worked just fine using SQL Server 2008 Express on Windows 7, but I need to get it to work with SQL Server 2014 Express on Windows 10, and I'm getting an error.

I start with an admin connection string:

```
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS2014;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI"
```

Then with that connection I create the database by executing:

```
CREATE DATABASE mobile
ON 
( NAME = mobile_dat,
    FILENAME = '...\path\mydb.mdf',
    FILEGROWTH = 5MB )
LOG ON
( NAME = 'mobile_log',
    FILENAME = '...\path\mydb.ldf',
    FILEGROWTH = 5MB );
```

And then I create a user:

```
CREATE LOGIN xxx WITH PASSWORD = 'xxx', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;

USE mobile

EXEC sp_adduser 'xxx', 'xxx';

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'xxx';
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_accessadmin', 'xxx';
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_securityadmin', 'xxx';
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_ddladmin', 'xxx';
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_backupoperator', 'xxx';
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'xxx';
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter', 'xxx';
```

At which point I disconnect and connect as the new user:

```
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS2014;Initial Catalog=mobile;User Id=xxx;Password=xxx;"
```

This worked fine with SQL Server 2008 Express on Windows 7, but on with SQL Server 2014 Express on Windows 10 I'm getting an error:

> Login failed for user 'xxx'.

Any ideas as to what I'm missing?

Comment: A `GO` statement after `use mobile`? `USE mobile` (new line) `GO`.

Comment: "Incorrect syntax near 'GO'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have mixed mode authentication enabled in the SQL Server Express 2014 installation?  It's disabled by default IIRC.

If it is enabled use Microsoft Management Studio to try and login and see what error it gives you.

Comment: I enabled it in SSMS, and that solved the immediate problem.  I even figured out how to enable mixed mode authentication in code. The problem is that it requires the service to be restarted, and that my program can't do. Looks like I'll be changing things to use Windows authentication.